# get trigger from IFTTT - using ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, ifttt

I'm using a Wemos mini, to switch on the light.

I'm trying to figure out how to combine `IFTTT` and `Sunset` and `Sunrise` from `Weather underground` to trigger the lights `ON`.

All examples I find, is how ESP triggers the `IFTTT` (using `IFTTTMaker`) but not the other way around, meaning ESP get triggered from `IFTTT` service.

Answer (score 3):

### If you want to send a "then that" trigger to your esp8266, you can use a *webhook*.

---

### However, you need to do some preparations on your home network:

- You need to have a webserver running on your esp8266.
- You need to enable port forwarding on your router for one port to be forwarded to your esp8266.
- You need to know your public facing IP-address or you need to use a DynDNS service.
- You need to be aware about the security implications of opening a public facing port and forwarding this to your esp8266.

---

### Here is what you then need to enter into the ifttt webhook action fields:

- URL: enter your public facing IP-address (including port that is forwarded to the esp8266) or your dynDNS address.
- Method/Content Type/Body: feel free to choose.

An example for a simple http call:

```
http://yourexternalip:yourport/msg?switch=0
```

---

### Here is what you need to implement on your esp8266:

On the esp8266 you need to have the webserver check for a **http request** as configured in your **webhook** and react according to your wishes.

Comment: Can you please share a code?

Comment: I don't have any own tested code that I could share, but maybe this tutorial about esp8266 as webserver could be helpful: https://tttapa.github.io/ESP8266/Chap10%20-%20Simple%20Web%20Server.html